# Checkbox component shifts in a table when clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having trouble to make the Angular Material checkbox component work.
When I click on the checkbox, the checkbox moves up so only half of the checkbox is displayed.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

```html
<table class="material-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>checked</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>{{ contract.OrderNumber }}</td>
            <mat-checkbox (change)="log(item)" [checked]="item.isChecked"> </mat-checkbox>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8600

Answer (score 1):

wandri commented in  https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8600 :

```
  mat-cell {
    overflow: visible;
  }
```

but maybe you need be more specific:

```
mat-cell.mat-cell, 
mat-header-cell.mat-header-cell 
{ 
    overflow: visible; 
}
```

Comment: I am using a normal table, not a mat-table. How do i do it with a normal table?